# Ansible - generate complex dictionary with set_fact (dictionary of lists)

Tags: ansible

I've the following var defined:

```
vars:
  rpms_list_output:
    - popt,1.16,14.el8,noarch
    - popt,1.16,14.el8,i686
    - popt,1.16,14.el8,x86_64
```

i'm trying to generate the following structure (using set_fact) with no luck so far:

```
new_packages:
  popt:
    - arch: noarch
      name: popt
      release: 14.el8
      version: 1.16
    - arch: i686
      name: popt
      release: 14.el8
      version: 1.16
    - arch: x86_64
      name: popt
      release: 14.el8
      version: 1.16
```

Below is the task that i'm running:

```
  - name: generate new_packages
    set_fact:
      new_packages: "{{ new_packages | default({}) | 
                        combine( { rpm_dict.name: [rpm_dict] } ) }}"
    vars:
      rpm_dict:
        name: "{{ item.split(',')[0] }}"
        version: "{{ item.split(',')[1] }}"
        release: "{{ item.split(',')[2] }}"
        arch: "{{ item.split(',')[3] }}"
    with_items: "{{ rpms_list_output }}"
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
    run_once: True
```

but it seems I'm not using combine correctly, as I'm getting only the last item (i.e. the list is overwritten instead of append):

```
new_packages:
  popt:
    - arch: noarch
      name: popt
      release: 14.el8
      version: 1.16
```

Comment: As you're using the same key every time with a different value every time, you're overriding the value at each item of the loop. Try something like `{{ new_packages | default({}) | combine( { rpm_dict.name: (new_packages | default({}))[rpm_dict.name] | default ([]) + [rpm_dict] } ) }}`

Comment: that did the trick :-)

Answer (score 0):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        popt: "{{ popt|default([]) +
                  [{'arch': _item.3,
                    'name': _item.0,
                    'release': _item.2,
                    'version': _item.1}] }}"
      loop: "{{ rpms_list_output }}"
      vars:
        _item: "{{ item.split(',') }}"
    - set_fact:
        new_packages: "{{ {}|combine({'popt': popt}) }}"
```

does the job

```yaml
  new_packages:
    popt:
    - arch: noarch
      name: popt
      release: 14.el8
      version: '1.16'
    - arch: i686
      name: popt
      release: 14.el8
      version: '1.16'
    - arch: x86_64
      name: popt
      release: 14.el8
      version: '1.16'
```